# Convert array of time into some interval of time array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am implementing the graph in Canvas. So I have x-axis and y-axis. I am converting both values in array form. x-axis pointed to time and y-axis pointed to volume data.
You can see screen shots for more idea:
[image]

This graph plotted based on some array.

[image]

Previously I was getting value:

> for Y-axis [377,622,42,188]
>   for X-axis   ["02.20","4:30","08:50","09:10"]

So I picked start time of X-axis(02.20) and end time(9:10), Divided into hours like ["02.20","03:00","4:30","05:00","06:00","07:00","08:50","09:10"].

And Y-axis put 0 in the array if data is not there of Y-axis array, According to X-axis.

```
call.all('data').get('navigation').then(function(resp){
      setTimeout(function(){
        var totalVolumeArr = _.map(resp.data,function(res){ return res.tot});
        lineData2.labels = _.map(resp.data,function(res,idx){
          var time = [];
          if (typeof resp.data[idx - 1] !== 'undefined') {
            if (((resp.data[idx - 1])._id.hr + 1) !== res._id.hr) {
              for (var i = resp.data[idx - 1]._id.hr + 1; i < res._id.hr; i++) {                    time.push('0' +i + ':00');
              }
            }
          }
          var x =  time.push(('0' + res._id.hr).slice(-2) + ':' + (''+ res._id.slot).slice(-2)+'0');            
          return  time;
        });

        var flatArray = [].concat.apply([],  lineData2.labels);
        _.map(resp.data,function(res,idx){
          var time=[];
          var tempArr=[];
          if (typeof resp.data[idx - 1] !== 'undefined') {
            if (((resp.data[idx - 1])._id.hr + 1) !== res._id.hr) {
              for (var i = resp.data[idx - 1]._id.hr + 1; i < res._id.hr; i++) {
                if(jQuery.inArray('0' +i + ':00', flatArray) !== -1)
                {
                  var indexValue='0' +i + ':00';
                  var indexPosition= flatArray.indexOf(indexValue);
                  totalVolumeArr.splice(indexPosition, 0, "0"); //push the 0 volume value into array of totalvolumearray
                }
              }
            }
          }
          return tempArr;
        })
    xAxisValue = flatArray;
    yAxisValue = totalVolumeArr;
});
```

Right now I want to rearrange  these two arrays flateArray and totalValumeArr.

You can think xAxisValue = ["02.20","4:30","08:50"]
              yAxisValue= [377,622,42]

**Expacted out put:**
**

> xAxisValue =
>   ["02:20","02:30","02:40","02:50","03:00","03:10","03:10","03:20","03:30","03:40","03:50","04:00","04:10","04:20","04:30","04:40","04:50","05:00","05:10","05:20","05:30","05:40","05:50","06:00","06:10","06:20","06:30","06:40","06:50","07:00","07:10","07:20","07:30","07:40","07:50","08:00","08:10","08:20","08:30","08:40"
>   "08:50"]

**
 **

> yAxisValue=
>   [377,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,622,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,42]

**
Above code working fine if I want to see hourly basis. But Now I want to set data 10 minutes interval of time. If data is not there then time should be there with 0 data volume. Please share your logic. Which is the best approach?

Comment: On your deleted question:      var result=array.map(function(time){
      [hours,mins]=time.split(":");
      hours= (+hours+5+~~(mins/60))%24;
      mins=(+mins+30)%60;
      return hours+":"+mins;
     });

Comment: Thanks @Jonas. thanks for helping me

Comment: @V SH ive answered while the question got closed :/ , and simply deleting wouldve been wasting of brain resources ;)

Comment: @ Jonas. I don't want to delete question. But contineusly 4 devote. So i think problem in my question

Comment: But It is showing array not defined I pass array in time.

Comment: @V SH array=["12:30", "15:30"]